# Creating/destroying an object in a static memory section

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer, memory-alignment, object-lifetime

Is the static memory section `alignas(alignof(T)) char bytes[sizeof(T)]` suitable to hold an instance of `T` during its lifetime by calling `std::construct_at(bytes, ...)` / `std::destroy_at(bytes)`? My instincts say, yeah, the alignment and size requirements are guaranteed, so after construction (since there are also trivially constructible types, I prefer to call it initialization) `reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes)` is a valid pointer to a completely valid instance of type `T`.

Am I missing something?

PS: I could also write `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> bytes` - in that case its memory would be referenced as `&bytes` or `std::addressof(bytes)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the static memory section `alignas(alignof(T)) char bytes[sizeof(T)]` suitable to hold an instance of T during its lifetime by calling `std::construct_at(bytes, ...)` / `std::destroy_at(bytes)`?

Yes.

> `reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes)` is a valid pointer to a completely valid instance of type T.
>
> Am I missing something?

You would still need to launder a pointer to reused memory:

```
T* ptr1 = std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes), ...); // valid
T* ptr2 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes)); // valid
std::destroy_at(ptr2); // valid, just like std::destroy_at(ptr1)
```

Comment: Good catch! `std::launder` always was something obscure to me, even since it didn't exist before C++17 where we simply did a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @plasmacel Yeah, before then we just had to play with UB, or always only use the pointer returned by placement new.

Comment: Should I also launder the pointer which is passed to `std::destroy_at`? Like `std::destroy_at(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes)));`.

Comment: @plasmacel Yes, you have to always launder when getting the pointer from `bytes`.

Comment: Note that `std::construct_at` takes a pointer type `T*`, where `T` is the type you want to make an instance of. So it is actually `std::construct_at(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes)), ...)`.

Comment: @plasmacel Yup. Good catch. I don't think laundering is needed there since `std::construct_at` won't indirect through the pointer. But it won't hurt either.